# Black part of page during capture with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, screenshot, casperjs, capture

I have a strange problem. I have to take screenshots from vk.com in album with comments.

In this case everything is ok:

[image]

But when i click to load more comments, the screenshot has a black lower part:

[image]

The code is pretty simple:

```
// click on image
casper.waitForSelector(".photo_row_img", function() {
    this.click('.photo_row_img');   
});

// get more comments
casper.waitForSelector("#pv_comments_header", function() {
    casper.click('#pv_comments_header');    
});

// take screenshot
casper.wait(10000, function() {     
    casper.captureSelector('capture.jpg', '#pv_photo_wrap'); 
});
```

I spent two days and still do not understand what's going on.

Comment: I've worked a little with casper, ghost, and selenium. Can you inspect the page and post what you're getting? If I were to warrant a guess it would be that the 2nd comment load is a nested iframe. I'm going to assume that you've tried varying the capture time so that's unlikely to be an issue. It's either a nesting problem, or the way in which more comments are inserted into the page somehow doesn't agree with your grab.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is the cod, after click on that i get more comment: <div id="pv_comments_header" class="clear " onclick="Photoview.comments()">  <div>Показати попередні 19 коментарів</div><div id="pv_comments_progress" class="progress"></div></div>
And i dont fully understand what do you mean: tried varying the capture time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution)
when i click on picture, open new window over existing
Window with picture bigger then body on document, and everything that extends beyond body height is black.
I simple just made more body height)

```
this.evaluate(function() {
    document.querySelector("body").style.height = yourNewHeight;                        
});
```

Comment: Hey, @G.F., how much the variable "yourNewHeight" should be ?

Comment: Should be height, that you need. Whatever you want

Comment: How I obtained the total height of the currentview (include the blackpart)? @G.F.